# Recovery image without root functionality for an Xperia Z1 Compact

Tags: rooting, backup, recovery-mode

A friend of mines child has a Sony Xperia Z1 Compact and a lot of what I would call Criminal Energy (he proved that on several occasions).

Because he did a lot of stuff on his phone which he is not supposed to do, we want to prevent him of finding out how to boot into the previously installed TWRP Recovery Mode, where he could root his phone and do other uncool stuff.

From what I found out, I am not able to remove TWRP, but could totally replace it with something else.

So my question is, are there any simple, Backup/Restore only, ***no root option, no File editing (eg. build.props)*** Recovery images available for me to flash on that particular smartphone or do i have any other options? (We already installed and configured Family Link, but that of course does not prevent booting in recovery mode)

Answer (score 0):

1. Re-flash the official recovery and boot images of the device.
2. Lock the bootloader and disable Developers option.

Official recoveries do not allow to do much i.e rooting, changing/editing build.prop file and other system files. It will buy you time until the child studies enough and figure out that it is possible to change the recovery and root the system.